# Runtime change tensorboard log directory

Tags: tensorboard

Once you launch Tensorboard, the server scans the log directory you passed as argument. Each new log you add there is managed by Tensorboad, which is cool.
But, is there a way to change runtime the log directory?
For instance I'd like to switch among a set of directories belonging to different projects.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: unfortunately no